# Startup Disk Creator fails to format USB drive

Tags: usb, format, startup-disk-creator, startup-disk

I'm trying to create a bootable Ubuntu disk using Startup Disk utility, but when I try to erase the USB memory, this appears:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.GLib.Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper", line 287, in Format
    partition = table.call_create_partition_sync(0, size, '0x0c', '', no_options, None)
GLib.Error: udisks-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error wiping newly created partition /dev/sdd1: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sdd1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sdd1: probing initialization failed: No such file or directory
 (0)
```

Comment: It is not. I've tryied to format on 2 separated drives and still nothing

Answer (score 3):

The `Startup Disk Creator` tool is known to having some issues to create the USB properly.
Instead use the `Disks` tool (`gnome-disk-utility`) to create the Ubuntu installation media.

Open `Disks` and select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right of the application.
Choose the Ubuntu installation ISO file and the USB drive to write it to and then start restoring.